# How to call math.factorial from numba with nopython mode?

Tags: python, numba

I need to compute factorials of large integers inside of a for loop that I would like to compile using numba. The `factorial` function in Python's math module seems to be fast. How can I call this function from numba using nopython mode? Unfortunately this function is not supported by numba currently https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/pysupported.html.

```
import math
from numba import njit

@njit
def factorial(n):
    return math.factorial(n)

factorial(2)
```

throws a TypingError:

`TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'factorial' of type Module(<module 'math' from '/anaconda3/envs/minimalcondaforge/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-darwin.so'>)`

Is there a way to call this function? Can I use `@overload` or `get_cython_function_address` as described here http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/extending/high-level.html? (I was not able to make it work so far, I am new to numba so I might just not be doing it right.) Also open to other suggestions for a fast factorial function in numba, but it needs to be able to handle large integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba can't compile Python's arbitrary-precision integers, so if you want to find exact factorials of integers larger than 20⁠—which at 2432902008176640000 is the most that can fit in a 64-bit integer⁠—then Numba unfortunately won't be helpful.

If you don't need the exact integer for large factorials, then you could define your factorial function as the equivalent `math.gamma(n+1)`, which does compile under Numba and has floating-point output. Even this only works up to `170!`, though, which is the largest that can fit in a 64-bit float.

Without arbitrary-precision numbers, larger factorials need to be represented in log form. For this you can use `math.lgamma(n+1)`, which also compiles under Numba and can return `log(n!)` for very high n.